# Convert string in to list(in pairs) in python

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to create the code for the exercise given by my prof. I am to turn piece of string(random) into a list, using lists(guessing .append())
The example that I got was this:

```
def string_to_list_in_pairs('abcd')
```

Should return:

```
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

I was using the code that I learned in class:

```
def string_to_list_in_pairs (st):
    newL2 = []
    for i in range(len(st)):
        newL2.append(st[i])
    return newL2
```

but I'm stuck on the part where it turns it into pairs. I know that with this equation I get

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

for string **'abcd'**
what do I have to add in, in order to make it into pairs? (we didn't learn iterate, prof wants us to use what we learned).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid do you mean that I should put in st[i+1] for .append(st[i]) part?

Comment: `range()` returns a list and `for` iterates over it. So what does "we didn't learn iterate" mean?

Answer (score 4):

```
def string_to_list_in_pairs (s):
    return [''.join(pair) for pair in zip(s[:-1], s[1:])]
```

#### Example

```
>>> string_to_list_in_pairs('abcd')
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

#### How it works

Note how the output looks.  The first characters in the three strings are `abc` which are just the input string without its last character: `s[:-1]`.

Now, look at the last characters in the three strings.  They are 'bcd' which are the input string without its first character: `s[1:]`.

We can combine those two with `zip` and it looks like:

```
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> s[:-1], s[1:]
('abc', 'bcd')
>>> zip(s[:-1], s[1:])
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd')]
```

This is almost the right answer.  Each tuple in the list has the right characters.  The only remaining issue is that it is a tuple and we want a string.  To convert a tuple to a string, we apply `join`.  This can be done for each tuple in that list via:

```
>>> [ ''.join(pair) for pair in [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd')] ]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

Or, putting it all together:

```
>>> [''.join(pair) for pair in zip(s[:-1], s[1:])]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

This just what the function defined above does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations('abcd', 2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two changes are required:

1. Adding `-1` to `range(len(st))`
2. Adding `+st[i+1]` to `newL2.append(st[i])`

Then:

```
def string_to_list_in_pairs (st):
    newL2 = []
    for i in range(len(st)-1):
        newL2.append(st[i]+st[i+1])
    return newL2
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> string_to_list_in_pairs('abcd')
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

Comment: or `newL2.append(st[i:i+2])`

Comment: oh, ok, I see. Thank you for the areas that I needed to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Use itertools

```
 from itertools import combinations 
 for i in combinations('abcd', 2):
     print ''.join(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations 
def string_to_list_in_pairs (st):
    newL2 = []
    for i in combinations(st, 2):
        newL2.append(''.join(i))
    return newL2

print string_to_list_in_pairs('abcd')
```

**Result**:

```
['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you provided you could try the following:

```
def string_to_list_in_pairs (st):
    newL2 = []
    for i in range(len(st)-1):
        newL2.append(st[i]+st[i+1])
    return newL2
```

The modifications that were made to your code were to reduce the number of times the for loop ran. This was done to ensure that during each iteration you were appending the character that was next to it therefore making a pair.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example without itertools. The rand_str line creates a random string and the for loop cuts it into two letter pieces:

```
from random import choice

rand_str="".join([x for x in map(lambda y: choice('ATCG'), range(100))])

duplex_list=[]
for y in range(0,len(rand_str),2):
    duplex_list.append(rand_str[y:y+2])

print rand_str
print duplex_list
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer,

```
def string_to_list_in_pairs(st):
    """
    Compute a list with char pairs from a string """

    # For strings with length 1 or 0
    if len(st) <= 1:
        return list(st)
    else:
        return [st[i:i+2] for i in range(len(st)-1)]
```

Results,

```
>>> string_to_list_in_pairs('')
[]
>>> string_to_list_in_pairs('a')
['a']
>>> string_to_list_in_pairs('ab')
['ab']
>>> string_to_list_in_pairs('abc')
['ab', 'bc']
>>> string_to_list_in_pairs('abcd')
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
>>> string_to_list_in_pairs('abcde')
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de']
```